# Compare Marker.getPosition() and LatLang

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

My app gets updated GPS coordinates periodically which I show using a Marker on map. I need to move the marker to a new position if the new GPS coordinates are different then what Marker is currently showing.

The problem is that comparing Marker.getPosition() is more accurate while LatLang is not, hence sometimes even when they are the same, my logic says they are different.

[image]

How to solve this issue?
Please note that the same LatLang i assign to Marker.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider that two `LatLng`s are virtually the same if the distance between them is less than a given tolerance.

You can use the `SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween` method from the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/)

```
float YOUR_TOLERANCE = 1; // 1 meter
if (SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(pos, buslatLng) < YOUR_TOLERANCE) {
    // Both locations are considered the same
}
```